# Sumproduct over multiple DF columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication, sumproduct

```
ID    height_1    area_1   in_1    height_2    area_2   in_2    height_3    area_3   in_3
1     4           20       1       7           87       1       2          21       1
2     10          83       1       12          32       1       9          41       0
3     16          78       1       12          17       0       np.nan     np.nan   np.nan
```

How can I calculate the sumproduct in a generic approch for each row looking like this...?

````
sumproduct = height_1 * area_1 * in_1 + height_2 * area_2 * in_2 + height_3 * area_3 * in_3 + ...  ```
````

For e.g. `row1 = 4 * 20 * 1 + 7 * 87 * 1 + 2 * 21 * 1`

My Dataframe has around 20 times `height_, area_, in_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wide_to_long` and `product` and `sum`

```
s = (pd.wide_to_long(df, i='ID', j='val', 
                     stubnames=['height','area','in'] ,sep='_', suffix='\d+')
       .product(1).sum(level=0))

Out[575]:
ID
1     731.0
2    1214.0
3    1248.0
dtype: float64
```

To assign it to `df`:

```
df['sumproduct'] = df.ID.map(s)
```

Or

```
df['sumproduct'] = s.values
```

Or

```
df['sumproduct'] = s.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['sum'] = 0
for i in range(1, 21):
   df['sum'] += df['height_{}'.format(i)] * df['area_{}'.format(i)] * df['in_{}'.format(i)]
```

Comment: it works when i do df = df.replace(np.nan, 0) before. is there a solution without replacing the nans?

Comment: maybe you can do something like `(0 if df['height_{}'.format(i)].isnull().bool() else df['height_{}'.format(i)])` or create a method for this.